# newcommand out of subsection

Tags: macros

I would like to create a new command based on subsection behavior.

Requirements are as follows:

- make a `\newcommand`
- support for alternative labels
- add `\vspace{-.2in}` after the label

The reason for making this is that I would not like to change the default behavior for existing / other subsections.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to copy the definition of `subsection` from your class (I'm assuming `article` here) and make the changes you want.

```
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
```

It has a counter, reset every section.

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
```

The section counter prefixes this counter when displayed

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

The fonts and spacing used for the heading

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
```

It's reset in the appendix

```
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

Uses a dotted line format in the table of contents

Comment: either i'm not awake yet, or this has the same name(s) as the existing subsection, which the op said s/he didn't want to be changed. ???

Comment: @barbarabeeton you missed out the `make the changes you want` bit. the above is as you say exactly a copy of subsection from article as the OP gave no indication of what changes are required